# I can't use multiple lines or add text to my Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

What I want to do is to send a message when the user uses the command

`/cotizacion`

That message should look like this:

```
Ultima Actualizacion: content[fecha]
Compra: content[compra]
Venta: content[venta]
Variacion: content[variacion]
```

What I cannot do is:

1. Add the text (e.g. Ultima Actualizacion)
2. Show the information in multiple lines (as shown above)

I have tried everything, using, or + and I'm really lost, as I am new to Python.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler
import requests
import re

def get_cotizacion():
    content = requests.get('https://mercados.ambito.com/dolar/oficial/variacion').json()
    fecha = content['fecha']
    compra = content['compra']
    venta = content['venta']
    variacion = content['variacion']
    cotizacion = (fecha+ compra+ venta+ variacion)
    return cotizacion

def cotizacion(bot, update):
    cotizacion = get_cotizacion()
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text= cotizacion)

def main():
    updater = Updater('#######')
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('cotizacion',cotizacion))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only know python so i can just tell you how to build a string from your json as i know nothing about the telegram bot. I´ll assume that the content is a string (if not you might need to convert it)

You can do this:

```
cotizacion = "Ultima Actualizacion: " + content[fecha] + \n + "Compra: " + ...
```

\n represents a line break and + adds mutliple strings together

You can convert numbers etc. to strings with str(my_number) - this might help if your json returns something other than a string
It wont work with lists though so check your data types.

If you dont want to hard code it like this you might want to use a dict like this:
{
    "Ultima Actualizacion": "fecha",
    "Compra": "compra",
     ...
}

There are probably better solutions but these are the first ones that came to my mind =)

Comment: Ok i used this solution and changed it a bit:
`cotizacion = "Ultima Actualizacion: " + fecha] + '\n' + "Compra: "...`

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use '\n' for new line. So your code could be like this.

```
cotizacion = '\n'.join('Ultima Actualizacion: ' + fecha, 'Compra: ' + compra, 'Venta: ' + venta, 'Variacion: ' + variacion)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I used the other option as it seemed easier for me to understand the code. Nevertheless, thanks a lot!

Comment: This won't work. Should be: `cotizacion = '\n'.join(['Ultima Actualizacion: ' + fecha, 'Compra: ' + compra, 'Venta: ' + venta, 'Variacion: ' + variacion])`